# What's the meaning of '-u' in 'git push -u origin master'?

Tags: git

I don't quite understand the meaning of `-u` in the `git push -u origin master` command. Can you explain what it's used for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-u` flag adds a reference to the upstream server you are pushing to. This lets you `git pull` without supplying additional arguments i.e. once you enter `git push -u origin master` you can then simply type `git pull` and this command will understand that in the future you mean `git pull origin master`.